# setting extra variables to Curl connection string

Tags: php, html, curl

I am using php/curl to make a connection to an external api. It is working fine but right now my connection string only references one variable from a form.

How can I make it references more than one?

This is how it looks like now

```
$curl_connection =curl_init('https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?host='.$_REQUEST['host']);
```

When making a call the above will look like this:
https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?**host=www.yourdomain.com**

My form has been updated and contains more input values which I want to reference as part of the curl connection and needs to look like this:
https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?**host=www.yourdomain.com**&**s=69.54.183.66**&**ignoreMismatch=on**

Each reference is seperated by the & symbol.

On my html form the input names are as follows:

- host
- s
- ignoreMismatch
  There are others aswell.. but the above is a sample

I hope that's clear enough for your to know what I am trying to do.

Here is a portion of my jquery / Ajax

```
var hostName = $("input#host").val();
var ignoreMismatch = $("#ignoreMismatch").val();
var fromCache = $("#fromCache").val();
dataString = "host=" + hostName + "&fromCache=" + fromCache + "&ignoreMismatch=" + ignoreMismatch;
enter code here
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api2.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
```

I can see this part is working. From  my web console I can see the URL is built and posted to the api2.php file.

For example https://172.21.121.37/labs/**api2.php?host=ocsp.verisign.com&fromCache=on&ignoreMismatch=on**

Here is my api2.php file which is currently only setup to receive host= string.

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =curl_init('https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?host='.$_REQUEST['host']);

///set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo $result;
//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
?>
```

This is working code by the way but I just wanted to give you guys more context as I tried some of the suggestions provided and they didn't work. If someone can help update my api2.php file I will test the updates.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
    $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}

$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1);

$ch = curl_init("https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?" . $encoded);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);       
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

Comment: i tried this but either its not working (as in i was getting a call back) or i am not factoring it into my api2.php file properly.. i have updated my post with my current code for you to look at.